# How do I convert a Map of Maps into JSON, and back, using GSON?

Tags: java, json, maps, gson

I've got a `Map<Integer, Map<Class<?>, Serializable>>` that I'm trying to store as a JSON string. Then, later, I'm trying to read from that same JSON formatted String to recreate the object. How would you do this using GSON?

Answer (score 1):

Rather then using Map of Map try to use class structure.

Or you can use following library to achieve the same.

```
com.google.gson.Gson.Gson()
```

use following method :

```
public static String getJSONString(Object jsonObject)
{
    if(jsonObject == null) return "";
    return new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not have any issue at all when trying to serialize `Map<Integer, Map<Class<?>, Serializable>>`, the problem is when trying to deserialize the JSON back. I guess you can write your own deserializer for the `Class<?>` depending on what you actually need, but deserializing `Serializable` is not possible.

`Serializable` is not a concrete class, it is an interface. You can't instantiate a `Serializable`, you can only instantiate a concrete class that implements `Serializable`. Sure you can write you own custom serializer/deserializer for `Serializable` by including the concrete class information inside the serialized JSON, but then you need to include all possible classes which implements `Serializable`, which is not realistic at all.

Reference: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types